# How to calculate width and height of element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have written this code to calculate the height and width of existing element when clicked. is this correct?

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var width = ddbar.clientWidth;
var height = ddbar.clientHeight;
alert(width);
alert(height);
});
```

Comment: Is this correct? Have you tried it? Where is ddbar defined?

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/height/, http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this code since you are using jQuery so that it can do its magic for browser compatibility:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var width = $(ddbar).width();
var height = $(ddbar).height();
alert(width);
alert(height);
});
```

Of course, jQuery approach will be slower: http://jsperf.com/jq-width-vs-client-width

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes grabbing element widths and heights extremely easy.

See:

- [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)
- [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) - includes padding and borders
- [.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) - includes the padding but not borders
- [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
- [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)
- [.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

Assuming that `dbbar` is a DOM element, all you need to do is:

```
    //get height of ddbar
    ddbar.height();

    //get width of ddbar
    ddbar.width();
```

Switch those out for inner/outer/etc as suits your requirements.

It should be really easy to test this?

Answer (score 0):

here you go,

http://jsfiddle.net/qR8Zw/1/

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var width = $('#div').width();
    var height = $('#div').height();
    alert("Width" + width);
    alert("Height" +height);
});
```

cheers